# How can I get a list of job builds that is related to a list of commit ids?

Tags: jenkins

Basically, I am looking for something like (pseudo-code)

```
def commitList = ["15ff9ad1", "25314adf"]
Jenkins.instance.getItem("some_project")
       .getAllItems()
       .collect { it.getBuilds().findAll { build -> commitList.contains(build.getHash()) }}
```

but rather in this form:

```
Jenkins.instance.getItem("some_project")
       .getAllItemsThatAreRelatedToCommits(commitList)
```

Comment: What do you mean "but rather in this form:"? `Jenkins.instance.getItem("some_project")` will return a WorkFlowJob(https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-job/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowJob.html) which doesn't have an inbuilt method to do what you need.

Comment: @ycr I was basically looking for an inbuilt method or easy way to get this information without having to extract it by myself in some hacky way. But then, I guess, this is not possible, right?